# build prod failed: spawn EACCES with ionic2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I build an hybrid app using Ionic 2.
I got a windows pc and using mac virtual box for Xcode.
I can run the app on browser and android just fine in my windows.
problem is when I'm moving to mac I'm doing the same things on node JS and I get errors.
I used those lines in the terminal

```
ionic start/run/emulate/build Vme2

sudo ionic start/run/emulate/build Vme2
```

none works
this is the error I get

```
> ionic-hello-world@ build /Users/amitaimazliah/Desktop/Vme2
> ionic-app-scripts build
[08:38:07]  ionic-app-scripts 0.0.38 
[08:38:07]  build prod started ... 
[08:38:07]  clean started ... 
[08:38:07]  clean finished in 3 ms 
[08:38:07]  copy started ... 
[08:38:07]  ngc started ... 
[08:38:07]  copy finished in 262 ms 
[08:38:07]  build prod failed: spawn EACCES 
[08:38:07]  ionic-app-script task: "build" 
[08:38:07]  Error: spawn EACCES 
npm ERR! Darwin 14.0.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "build"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! ionic-hello-world@ build: `ionic-app-scripts build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the ionic-hello-world@ build script 'ionic-app-scripts build'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the ionic-hello-world package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ionic-app-scripts build
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs ionic-hello-world
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ionic-hello-world
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/amitaimazliah/Desktop/Vme2/npm-debug.log
Caught exception:

undefined



Mind letting us know? https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues



[08:38:07]  lint started ... 

[08:38:08]  tslint: src/pages/home/home.ts, line: 57 

            Unused method: 'setNewPhotos' 

      L57:  private setNewPhotos()

[08:38:08]  lint finished in 1.27 s 

(node:2376) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: channel closed
```

any ideas what am I doing wrong?
thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have problem when build app.Can you try use this command '

```
ionic hooks add
```

Cheer !

Comment: I found the solution

Comment: had to do 
$ionic platform remove ios
$ionic hooks add 
$ionic platform ios

Comment: The files in the hooks folders have to be executable (755 or -rwxr-xr-x)